# Makefile waiting for pressing enter key

Tags: makefile

I've got this makefile target:

```
doc:
    @cd doku; \
    make clean > /dev/null 2>/dev/null; \
    make > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

If the make inside this target is ok, it ends normaly, but if make inside target doc returns an error, it stays "stuck". After I pressing enter, it ends normally with:

```
make: *** [doc] Error 2
```

Is there any option to end make without pressing the `Enter` key?

Comment: You should remove the output redirection to find out why it is expecting any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `$(MAKE)` when invoking sub-makes, not `make`.  This is really a shell question, not a make question, but if you don't want the process to read input you can redirect stdin from `/dev/null`:

```
make >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null
```